# How can change Flutter SliverApbar ExpandedHeight more than 250.0?

Tags: flutter, flutter-sliver

I want to use SliverApbar in my project but when i set ExpandedHieght value more than 250.0 it is not resize de flexibleSpace area. Could you someone help me how we can do this?

Comment: `SliverAppBar(expandedHeight: 600.0, ...` - I've tried this - it works totally fine. I don't know why you have a problem

Comment: please post your code

Comment: thanks i found the problem :) Problem was image height. When i set image height it works :)

Answer (score 0):

The following is working example. Give it a try and let me know if issue persist.

```
class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return CustomScrollView(
      slivers: <Widget>[
        SliverAppBar(
          expandedHeight: 300.0,
          flexibleSpace: FlexibleSpaceBar(background: Image.asset("assets/food.jpg", fit: BoxFit.cover,)),
        ),
        SliverList(delegate: SliverChildListDelegate(_buildSliversList())),
      ],
    );
  }

  List<Widget> _buildSliversList() {
    return List.generate(100, (index) {
      return ListTile(title: Text("Index = $index"));
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: thank i found the problem :) Problem was image height. When i set image height it works :)